# Url rewrite for restful api php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite

I have developed apis in core php. For this i have a separate folder on root of my site. named as api with in that folder i have v1 folder which contains my index.php files. 
I am handling all the api calls on index.php like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['method'])){
    $myApi = new MyApi();
$response = array();
    switch($_POST['method'])
    {
        case 'login':
        $response['result'] = $myApi ->login($_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);
        break;
        case 'verify':
        $response['result'] = $myApi ->verify($_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);
        break;
}
```

For this i am sending method name in request (as POST) of each request. 
I am now accessing the apis like this 
site.com/api/v1/index.php   (This is working fine).
But i need to access the apis my function name.
site.com/api/v1/login

I know a way through htaccess  but i am not clear with it . I have searched alot. What should i write in my htaccess file for the given directory structure?
Where should i place my htaccess file; either on root of site or root of V1 folder?

Please share ?

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite `/api/v1/login` URI to —> `/api/v1/index.php`, add this rule into `.htaccess` inside `v1` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Are there any other rewrite rules in the doc root .htaccess or inside `api` directory?

Comment: No. It is only present in V1 . I have one file on site root named as web.config which contains this 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: It's IIS config, not apache. Make sure you're using apache to serve these files.